# cannot install libreoffice on debian sid

Tags: debian, apt

Using Debian sid. I cannot install libreoffice as I get this error:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libreoffice : Depends: libreoffice-base but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libreoffice-calc but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libreoffice-core (= 1:4.4.5-2) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libreoffice-draw but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libreoffice-impress but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libreoffice-math but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libreoffice-report-builder-bin but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libreoffice-writer but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer but it is not going to be installed or
                        libreoffice-avmedia-backend-vlc but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: python3-uno (>= 4.4.0~beta2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: What does `apt-cache policy libreoffice-core` say?

Comment: @n.st: libreoffice-core:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:4.4.5-2
  Version table:
     1:4.4.5-2 0
        500 htp://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ unstable/main amd64 Packages
     1:4.4.5-1 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

Answer (score 1):

You can't, the maintainer has to do it.

Debian sid is currently undergoing the disruptive [gcc5 transition](https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel-announce/2015/08/msg00000.html), which is causing many uninstallability issues like this one (libreoffice isn't the only thing in the same boat; most of KDE has the same problem).

You can try installing libreoffice from stretch (testing), which should still work for the moment. Alternatively, wait until the transition is over.

Comment: I see. Thank you. Well, that serves me right for running sid without understanding the ecosystem.

Comment: related: can this also affect aptitude? I can't run it: `aptitude: symbol lookup error: aptitude: undefined symbol: _ZN7cwidget7widgets5pager8set_textERKSsPKc`

Comment: If you want to run sid (which is fine, I do it too) then I recommend subscribing to the debian-devel-announce mailinglist, where such transitions are always announced.

Comment: Yes, the transition affects software written in c++, which includes aptitude.